# recover git repository from a force push

Tags: git

I'm having a problem with my git repository. Basically what I did was to run a force push into master (I don't remember the reasons behind that). That caused the branch to diverge, in fact if I pull from development:

```
~/workspace/my-project(master*) » git pull origin development
From https://github.com/xxxx/xxxxx
 * branch            development -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 77239c7..958a5ff
Fast-forward
 .eslintrc.js                                                         |   17 -
 .gitignore                                                           |    4 +-
// other files differences...
```

But then when I try to commit:

```
~/workspace/my-project(master) » git commit -a
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 430 and 20 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

if I try to pull from master into master I get this error:

```
~/workspace/my-project(master) » git pull origin master
From https://github.com/xxxx/xxxxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I have the hash of the forced push commit, what should I do to be able to merge development into master?

Comment: The `unrelated histories` error message is scary.  The easiest fix which you could have done, I think, would be to just force push immediately with the correct version of `master`, or, that failing, maybe some fairly recent stable version.  I can't answer this, because I don't know what exactly is the state of repo at this point.

Comment: You just learned to never use force push but prefer '--force-with-lease'! (that way you would have easily fixed the remote history using the reflog)

Comment: This is probably not the best solution, but as an idea: You could do `git merge origin/master --alow-unrelated-histories` and resolve the merge conflicts, then (force?) push the fixed solution again